# Coordinate vectors as a basis for $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following exercise:

"Let S = {$v_1, v_2, ... v_n$} is a basis for a vectorial space V of dimension equal to n.

prove { $[v_1]_S$, $[v_s]_S$, ... $[v_n]_S$} is a basis for $R^n$."

I know that a coordinate vector $[v]_s$ is the sequence of coordinates {$c_1, c_2,...c_n$} from **w**=$c_1 v_1 + c_2v_2+ ... + c_nv_n$ where **w** is a vector from V.

But, what is $[v_i]_S$ ?

Following the same definition, this coordinate vector will be formed by all the coefficients {$d_1, d_2, ... d_3$} such as any $v_i$ part of S can be written as follows:

$v_i$= $d_1 z_1$ + $d_2z_2+ ... + d_iz_i$

My doubt is: who are these {$z_1, z_2, ... z_n$} ?? They would be the basis vectors in other context, but as far as I know, there is no such thing as "the basis of the basis".

So I'm thinking that maybe the $z_i$ vectors are the vectors from S themselves. In this case, I could prove that {$[v1]_S, [v_2]_S, ... [v_n]_S$} are the standard basis in fact. And from here, I would need only to prove why the standard basis is a basis for every space, which I already know.

Is my assumption $v_i=z_i$ right? Or I should take another perspective?

I'm using the book "Introductory linear algebra: an applied first course" 8th ed. - Bernard Kolman and David R. Hill, as a reference.

Comment: Yeah I think it is correct that in your notation $v_1=z_i$, hence $\{[v_i]_S\}$ is just the standard basis.

Answer (score 1):

Since $v_i=0\cdot v_1+\dots +1\cdot v_i+\dots 0\cdot v_n,$ we get $[v_i]_S=e_i:=\begin {pmatrix}0\\\vdots \\1\\\vdots \\0\end {pmatrix}.$

Thus we have the standard basis vectors,  from which the result follows.